# python script leaves zombie processes

Tags: python, linux

So I ran some python script on some files by

```
ls * | xargs python myscript.py
```

After the process finished normally, I looked at the process by

```
ps aux
```

I find that the process is still in the list. I have to manually kill it. Why is this? Here is my python script.

```
import sys
filex = open(argv[1])
for line in filex:
    do sth here.
```

Comment: **Which** process is still alive?  `ls`?  `xargs`?  One instance of `python`?  Many instances of `python`?  Best to show the relevant output from `ps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have skipped it in your post are you not calling close() on the file afterwards?

Try calling filex.close() at the end or alternatively use 'with':

```
with open(argv[1]) as filex:
    for line in filex:
        #do the things
```